# for every simple graph G with minimum degree more than (n-1)/2 prove that G is connected

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

let G be a simple graph with minimum degree of (n-1)/2 that n is the number of vertices. prove that G is connected

Comment: What is your work so far?

Comment: @JackFrost i just proved this for even numbers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an arbitrary vertex in the graph. It's connected to at least $\frac{n-1}{2}$ other vertices. Hence, the connected component of the graph containing our vertex has at least $\frac{n+1}{2}$ vertices in it. This is more than half of the vertices in the graph, and so we're done, since if every connected component has more than half the points in it, there can't be more than one!

I'm assuming here that the minimum degree is $\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$, if the floor is taken then $K_{n/2,n/2}$ is a counterexample.